# Grok Filter not adding new fields | Logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, filebeat, grok

We have the below grok filter configured for our journlabeat. The same was deployed on our local for filebeat was working fine but isn't adding the new fields on journalbeat.

```
filter {

    grok {
      patterns_dir => ["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-patterns-core-4.1.2/patterns"]
      match => { "message" => [
        '%{IPV4:client_ip} - - \[%{HTTPDATE:date}\] "%{WORD:method} %{URIPATH:request} %{URIPROTO:protocol}\/[1-9].[0-9]" (%{NUMBER:status}|-) (%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) "(%{URI:url}|-)" %{QUOTEDSTRING:client}'
        ]
        break_on_match => false
        tag_on_failure => ["failed_match"]
      }
    }
}
```

We tried adding the mutate filter for adding new fields using below but it isn't fetching the value and is printing the scalar values itself (example: %{client_ip}).

```
mutate {
        add_field => {
           "client_ip" => "%{client_ip}"
           "date" => "%{date}"
           "method" => "%{method}"
           "status" => "%{status}"
           "request" => "%{request}"
        }
      }
```

The log which we are trying to match is as below.

```
::ffff:172.65.205.3 - - [09/Jul/2020:11:32:52 +0000] "POST /v1-get-profile HTTP/1.1" 404 71 "https://mycompany.com/customer/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
```

Could someone let me know what exactly are we doing wrong. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can't replicate, your pattern worked fine for me. What version of logstash are you using? Also, why are you setting the `patterns_dir` if you are going to point to the default patterns dir?  There is no need for it. Try to grok field by field until you see what is giving you the failed match error, for example use `%{IPV4:client_ip} %{GREEDYDATA:other_fields}` to see if it works, then start adding the other fields until it stop working.

Comment: Thanks leandrojmp for looking into this. The issue was with version incompatibility of ElasticSearch and Logstash. This was fixed after upgrading the elasticsearch.
The filtering idea is really great. It helped in creating my other filter. Thank you so much. :)